# Login via passport facebook strategy with angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

I have implemented client side routing using 'Angular UI router'. I am using passport facebook strategy at the server side to handle facebook based authenticatoin.

I have my angular routes as follows:

```
angular.module('homepage').
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        // INDEX STATES  ========================================
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '../../html/partials/partial-index.html'
        })

        // HOME PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '../../html/partials/partial-home.html'
        });

});
```

Now i initiate the authentication on click to following link:

```
<a class="clickable" href="/auth/facebook">Log In</a>
```

Following are my server side routes:

```
// route for facebook authentication and login
app.get('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        scope : 'email'
    }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/success',
        failureRedirect : '/login'
    }));

app.get('/success', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // client side redirection without passing user info
    res.redirect('/#/home');
});
```

On authentication success, my page reloads and loads 'localhost:8888/#/home' and loads the 'home' route state. **But the issue is that i have not recieved any user info at the client side after redirection happened.**

Ideally i would like to do something as follows:

```
app.get('/success', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    // what i would like to do ideally
    res.json({
        path: '/#/home',
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

But I dont know how to pass this info to angularjs current page context from nodejs routes. How can i implement this.

What is the good approach to authenticate via facebook strategy and then do angular route redirection while passing user info to angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom response handler for passport when you use a  strategy. Like this:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Are you wrote that?

Don't forget about user serialization:

```
// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: How does this relate to my question.

Comment: If I understand right, there is no user info in `req.user`, right?

Comment: My bad, the user not received that i mentioned is for angularjs. I am able to do authentication with passport and get user info in nodejs.

Comment: In this case, could you specify how do you try to push user data to angular?

Comment: I am not able to push user data. I can either redirect user or push data. Not both at the same time.